# How do I rigorously show $f(\cap \mathcal{C}) \subset \cap f(\mathcal{C})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I've already proved that $f(\cap \mathcal{C}) \subset \cap f(\mathcal{C})$. I'm going to mark numbers because they will be useful for my questions.

$\Rightarrow$

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of sets $C_n \subset \mathcal{C}$.
>
> Let $y \in f(\cap \mathcal{C})$.
>
> $(1)$ Then $x \in \cap \mathcal{C}$.
>
> Then $\forall C \subset \mathcal{C}$ we have $x \in C$.
>
> So $\forall C \subset \mathcal{C}$ we have $y \in f(\mathcal{C})$.
>
> So $y \in \cap f(\mathcal{C})$.

$(1)$ First of all, if there exists a $f(x)$, does that imply there exists an $f^{-1}(f(x))$? Or, if there exists an $f^{-1}(f(x))$, does that imply there exists an $f(x)$? I think only the latter is true because the existence of an image does not imply the existence of a pre-image, but the existence of a pre-image does imply the existence of an image.

$(2)$ THE MOST IMPORTANT QUESTION: The converse would follow directly but that would show $=$, not $\subset$. So would I be assuming something incorrectly?

Comment: While the converse is NOT generally true, it is easily proved to be true if $f$ is an *injection*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, if you have an element in the image under a function, there *must* be something that mapped to it (otherwise it wouldn't be in the image). Perhaps you're confusing this with taking an arbitrary element in the range; this indeed does not necessarily have a preimage (take $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for example, with $y=2$). Also beware that the preimage of a single point may not consist if a single point (in the same example, what is $f^{-1}(1)$?).

To see the converse fail, take the following example: $\Bbb R=\Bbb Q\cup \Bbb Q^c$ and define $f$ to be your favorite constant function; I'll say $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then the left-hand side of your containment is the empty set, while the right-hand side is $\{0\}$.

Comment: "Then the left-hand side of your containment is the empty set, while the right-hand side is {0}." Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Secondly: How do I show it fails for the general case, i.e. formally show it?

Comment: Lastly, for the inverses, not an explicit function for it exists. Take $y=x^{1/2},x=−4$.

Comment: @Jossie: The image of the empty set is just the empty set (do you see that $\Bbb Q\cap\Bbb Q^c=\varnothing$?). What do you mean by the second question; how do you show it fails for the general case? To address your last question, correct, there does not always exist an explicit inverse function. Sometimes we can only argue the existence of it.

Comment: you wrote $\cup$ not $\cap$; am I mistaken?

Comment: Correct. Take $\mathcal{C}=\Bbb R$, $C_1=\Bbb Q$ and $C_2=\Bbb Q^c$. Then $C_1,C_2\subseteq\mathcal{C}$. Thus $f(C_1\cap C_2)=\varnothing$ for any function with domain the real numbers. The example above shows that $f(C_1)\cap f(C_2)$ need not be empty.

Comment: so whether an explicit function existed for the inverse is irrelevant here?

Comment: Right; again, there need not be an inverse. In general, only one-to-one functions can have an inverse function; otherwise, the inverse isn't well-defined. Even in the one-to-one cases, a closed form for the inverse function might not exist.

Comment: Also, by the converse It didn't have anything to do with  $\cup$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete proof which may help explain why only one of the directions is true in general.

But first, let's define slightly different notations to prevent confusion between expressions like $\;f(x)\;$, $\;f(C)\;$, and $\;f(\mathcal{C})\;$: we write the last two as $\;f[C]\;$ and $\;f[\![\mathcal{C}]\!]\;$, respectively, so that we have the following definitions:
\begin{align}
(0) \;\;\; & y \in f[V] \;\equiv\; \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in V \rangle \\
(1) \;\;\; & W \in f[\![\mathcal{B}]\!] \;\equiv\; \langle \exists V : f[V] = W : V \in \mathcal{B} \rangle \\
\end{align}

With these notations, the statement to prove is
$$
f[\cap \mathcal{C}] \;\subseteq\; \cap f[\![\mathcal{C}]\!]
$$

Our strategy is to start at (what I think is) the most complex side, the right hand side, calculate all its elements $\;y\;$ by expanding the definitions, and then seeing where the laws of logic lead us.

---

For all $\;y\;$,
\begin{align}
& y \in \cap f[\![\mathcal{C}]\!] \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall W : W \in f[\![\mathcal{C}]\!] : y \in W \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition $(1)$"} \\
& \langle \forall W : \langle \exists V : f[V] = W : V \in \mathcal{C} \rangle : y \in W \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: rewrite $\;\exists V\;$ in range of $\;\forall W\;$ to a $\;\forall\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall W,V : f[V] = W \land V \in \mathcal{C} : y \in W \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: one-point rule for $\;W\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall V : V \in \mathcal{C} : y \in f[V] \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition $(0)$"} \\
& \langle \forall V : V \in \mathcal{C} : \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in V \rangle \rangle \\
(*) \;\;\; \Leftarrow & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;\exists\forall \Rightarrow \forall\exists\;$} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- without any knowledge about $\;f\;$ or $\;\mathcal{C}\;$,} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"-- }}\text{this is the only thing we can do;} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"-- }}\text{this is where $\;\cap\;$ and applying $\;f\;$ are exchanged"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : \langle \forall V : V \in \mathcal{C} : x \in V \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in \cap \mathcal{C} \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition $(0)$"} \\
& y \in f[\cap \mathcal{C}] \\
\end{align}
By the definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, this completes the proof.

---

Note that the key step $(*)$ cannot be reversed in general because of the essentially one-directional law $\;\exists\forall \Rightarrow \forall\exists\;$.

Finally, looking at the proof as a whole, I am pleasantly surprised by the simple structure: until the key step $(*)$ we are only expanding definitions and simplifying, and after that point we immediately go back to the set and function level using the definitions.